# How to get corresponding Ubuntu release codename on its derivative (Mint, Elementary, ...)?

Tags: apt, derivatives

I want to create a `deb` string for my APT repository.
Now it looks like
`deb http://sitename $(lsb_release -cs) main`

Ubuntu derivatives display their own distribution name in `lsb_release -cs` (like `sarah` on Mint). Is there a universal way to get upstream Ubuntu version on Ubuntu itself and its derivatives?

Comment: `cat /etc/version` or `cat /proc/version` might get you what you want.

Comment: I need an Ubuntu distribution codename, not kernel version string.

Comment: Oh. Well in any case, I suggest you edit the title. Your question already has 2 close votes for being off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't define any standard way to do this. A derivative may or may not include the name of its upstream release somewhere in a file.

The best way is probably to use some package versions to guess the upstream version. The package `libc6` would be a good candidate for that, `coreutils` may be another one.